# GPG error: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available

Tags: gnupg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix the GPG error “NO_PUBKEY”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

after `sudo apt-get update` I get this error:

```
W: GPG error: http://archive.hivemind.me all Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3C962022012520A0
```

Comment: Hi!

I tried, but no success, look:

....
$sudo apt-key adv --keyserver archive.hivemind.me --recv-keys 3C962022012520A0
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /etc/apt/secring.gpg --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver archive.hivemind.me --recv-keys 3C962022012520A0
gpg: requesting key 012520A0 from hkp server archive.hivemind.me
?: archive.hivemind.me: Connection refused
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Connection refused
gpg: no valid Open

Comment: The website appears to be either down or misconfigured, I can't get to it either.

Comment: You can check this [SO thread](http://askubuntu.com/questions/308760/w-gpg-error-http-ppa-launchpad-net-precise-release-the-following-signatures/) for solution. Link to [related site](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2013/04/w-gpg-error-httpppalaunchpadnet-precise.html)

Answer (score 231, accepted):

Run the following in your terminal,

```
 sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3C962022012520A0 
 sudo apt-get update
```

References: [How do I fix the GPG error "NO_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey-without-terminal)

You need to replace the key (3C962022...) with the one that is displayed in the error message in the terminal.

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: Me too! I'll have to read up on  this.

Comment: How do you achieve this on OSX?

Comment: If you get a `keyserver timed out` error, do `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3C962022012520A0`

Comment: @arjun I received a `gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure`, but using this command it worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: Worked for me on 18.04

Comment: gpg: failed to start the dirmngr '/usr/bin/dirmngr': No such file or directory

Comment: I got `gpg: keyserver receive failed: No data`

Answer (score 15):

When you add a third-party repository, you should also add its key to your system. The public key is a string which identifies that certain repository. You can find some more information on this and how to add the key [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Authentication%20Tab).