# Can't update anything on computer, getting GPG error

Tags: apt, updates

I tried to download Spotify for Linux a few days ago and I made a small error and it caused a message which kept me from downloading Spotify. After 2 hours I realized the mistake and I was to download Spotify, but now I can't update anything at all on my computer, and I'm scared because I might have messed with a file and deleted it or ruined it.

Now I have no idea what to do. What should I do? By the way, I'm not a computer person.

This is what it says when I try and update using `sudo apt-get update` on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
E: GPG error: http://apt2.pennmanor.net trusty InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
```

And it is not a network proxy problem because I forgot the network and readded it and it still didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Got NODATA issue: 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/474549/got-nodata-issue-nodata-does-the-network-require-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

Borrowed from this issue: [GPG error - NO_PUBKEY](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2257304)

Try the following to remove all PPA keyrings.

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/*
```

Not exactly the same, but I believe it will resolve your issue.

Comment: This is what I got: rm: cannot remove ‘/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/’: Is a directory

Comment: Note the * after the final /. It means remove everything in that directory, not the directory itself. You may also want to have a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/474549/got-nodata-issue-nodata-does-the-network-require-authentication) if the previous doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. How do I remove everything in the directory?

Comment: That was the command I posted in my answer. sudo will give you the super user privileges and rm is the command for remove. Then you have the pathname, and the asterisk(*) at the end, means everything found within the /trusted.gpg.d/ directory.

Comment: I put that and I got: `rm: cannot remove ‘/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/*` : No such file or directory    Sorry I am very inexperienced with laptops so could you explain a little more what the pathname is?

Comment: You can also look at that directory with your graphical file explorer. Sounds like it is just empty. Have a look at the link I put in my above comment. That may have some more information for you, though not exactly the same problem, it may be close enough to  get you up and running.

Comment: I think you may be able to get rid of any 'hiccups' in the system by grabbing a file with wget. Try `wget -O /dev/null http://speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com/downloads/test10.zip` to just download something through your system.

Comment: Ok, it downloaded I will restart my computer and check

Comment: Ok so I still get the same error...

Comment: Have you looked through the link that I sent, and tried anything from there? A lot of great suggestions, and many seem to have worked for others.

Comment: Yes, none of them seem to work. I saw that post before and I didn't get much help...

Comment: Have you tried all of the maintenance actions within Software Sources, as well as disabling any 'Additional Repositories'?

Comment: No, how would I do that?

Comment: From the menu, select Administration > Software Sources. Within the Maintenance area, run all options, from top to bottom. Then, within the Additional Repositories section, deselect (don't remove) all options.

Comment: Can't find admin or Software Sources

Comment: [This video will show](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HsKg2dw304c)

Comment: Ok I selected all and deselected additional repositories. Now what should I do?

Comment: Can try again with an update.

Comment: I think it worked but I am not sure `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done                
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Comment: You can add back repositories now, and remove any you have issues with.

Comment: so now I am getting this...`W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY FC14671BA89CA06C
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`

Comment: Have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20725/gpg-error-the-following-signatures-couldnt-be-verified-because-the-public-key)

Comment: I followed it and got this...`W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`

Comment: You will just have to remove that one from ppas. Most likely due to Chrome not being offered for linux in 32 bit versions any longer. See [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome)