# How do I install a specific lower minor version of gcc using package manager?

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, gcc

I am running an Ubuntu 14.04-4 64bit. `gcc --version` returns

```
(Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.4
```

Yet, I need version `4.8.2-10`.
What I tried:

1. I found the specific gcc version in a debian [snapshot repository](http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20131213T160912Z).
2. I adapted my `/etc/apt/sources.list` to contain the following two lines only:

   ```
   deb http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20131213T160912Z unstable main    
   deb-src http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20131213T160912Z unstable main
   ```
3. As suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20725/gpg-error-the-following-signatures-couldnt-be-verified-because-the-public-key) I added the required key
4. I did `sudo apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update`
5. `sudo apt-get remove gcc`
6. `sudo apt-get install gcc`. This returned:

   ```
    ...
    Preparing to unpack .../gcc_4%3a4.8.2-1_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking gcc (4:4.8.2-1) ...
    Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
    Setting up gcc (4:4.8.2-1) ...
   ```

Unfortunately, `gcc --version` still returned
`gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.4`

Removing and re-installing `gcc-4.8` and `gcc-4.8-base` returned in an error (unmet dependencies) or a strange warning (uninstalling more than 700mb).

How can I install this specific gcc version?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the packages you want over [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package_metas/list?name=gcc-4.8) and install them using `gdebi`.

Answer (score -1):

You can have as many versions of gcc as you want, installed at the same time :
The default versions for Ubuntu 14.04 are → →

```
$ sudo apt-get install g++-4.4 g++-4.6 g++-4.7 g++-4.8
```

... where "4.8" = version 4.8.2 is the system compiler, /usr/bin/{ gcc, g++ }

Using one of the other compilers, examples : `$ gcc-4.4 file.c` ,,, 
`$ export CC=gcc-4.4 CXX=g++-4.4 && [other command]` ,,,
like  `$ export CC=gcc-4.4 CXX=g++-4.4 && ./configure`

---

Comment: I don't see how this answers my question. How can I install the exact version I mentioned in my question?

Comment: Not a good idea to replace the system compiler. But you can of course compile the older version 4.8.2, by building with configure option `--program-suffix=482` http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/installing-gcc-4-8-2-on-opensuse-12-1-a-4175484799/#4

Comment: ? Why do you want "4.8.2-10" . Seems that the original "April 2014 packages" were : cpp-4.8_4.8.2-19ubuntu1_amd64.deb, gcc-4.8-base_4.8.2-19ubuntu1_amd64.deb, gcc-4.8_4.8.2-19ubuntu1_amd64.deb, g++-4.8_4.8.2-19ubuntu1_amd64.deb → → https://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.8/

Comment: I downloaded the package and did an `dpkg -i gcc-4.8_4.8.2-19ubuntu1_amd64.deb`. I got a "dependency problem" error. It says that `gcc-4.8 depends on cpp-4.8 (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1); however:
  Version of cpp-4.8 on system is 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3`

Comment: Please also see https://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-defaults/ -

Comment: if I try to install cpp it says: `cpp-4.8 depends on gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1); however:
  Version of gcc-4.8-base:amd64 on system is 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3.`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what to do with the link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40068/discussion-between-stackoverflowwww-and-knud-larsen).

Comment: To install new packages, please first remove { gcc-4.8-base, gcc, g++, libstdc++-4.8-dev  }. The issues will probably be : libgcc1, libstdc++ , which you cannot remove or downgrade, I think.

Comment: I got it installed. I needed the right order:  gcc-4.8-base_4.8.2-19ubuntu1_amd64.deb 
cpp-4.8_4.8.2-19ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libgcc-4.8-dev_4.8.2-19ubuntu1_amd64.deb 
gcc-4.8_4.8.2-19ubuntu1_amd64.deb