# Intel graphic ppa error after apt-get update

Tags: drivers, apt, graphics

how can i ignore this message?

```
W: GPG error: https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/16.04/main xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 56A3DEF863961D39
W: The repository 'https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/16.04/main xenial InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Its from intel update gfx.

Comment: It is better not to install anything from `download.01.org`. You will get only trouble.

Comment: I agree with @Pilot6. Suggest you remove that repository. Cheers, Al

Comment: @Pilot6 what do you suggest as an alternative ?

Answer (score 16):

I managed to solve it for Ubuntu 16.04 and 16.10 by running following commands

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-GROUP-KEY-ilg -O - | sudo apt-key add -
wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg -O - | sudo apt-key add -
wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg-2 -O - | sudo apt-key add -
wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg-3 -O - | sudo apt-key add -
wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg-4 -O - | sudo apt-key add -
```

Comment: Works but shows  `W: https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/16.04/main/dists/xenial/InRelease: Signature by key 09D6EF97BFB38E916EF060E756A3DEF863961D39 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)`  at the end of apt update.

Comment: This works definately.

Answer (score 10):

Try to add the key (replace `56A3DEF863961D39` with your missing key):

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 56A3DEF863961D39
sudo apt-get update
```

References and further reading:

- [GPG error: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20725/gpg-error-the-following-signatures-couldnt-be-verified-because-the-public-key)
- [How do I fix the GPG error "NO_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)
- [Invalid filename extension in apt sources.list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/843976/invalid-filename-extension-in-apt-sources-list)

Comment: this should be the  accepted answer.

Comment: Was not sure about this method, but it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Open a terminal & run

`wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg-4 -O - | sudo apt-key add -`

This will allow updates, you'll get the weak digest algorithm warning but it's just a warning at the moment. (in 16.04