# Invalid filename extension in apt sources.list

Tags: apt, software-sources

```
N: Ignoring file 'yandex-browser.list.save.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'yandex-browser.list.save.2' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Type 'andex.ru/yandex-browser/deb' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yandex-browser.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run in terminal

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yandex-browser*
```

and the problem should be fixed.

Some script or you corrupted some sources.list files while installing Yandex Browser.

Comment: @loorascal did this solve your problem? Then please mark the answer as "accepted".