# apt-get giving warnings on programs I've uninstalled

Tags: apt, uninstall

I uninstalled a program using the command

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove programName
```

but when I ran sudo apt-get update it still return errors on that program's keys. So I then uninstalled the program's key using

```
sudo apt-key del AAAAAAAA
```

but then I get errors from sudo apt-get update about the keys. Specifically I am trying to completely remove Epson drivers, and these are the errors:

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/op/stable/debian lsb3.2 Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E5E86C008AA65D56

W: Failed to fetch http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/op/stable/debian/dists/lsb3.2/Release.gpg The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E5E86C008AA65D56

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I just want everything about these Epson drivers removed so I don't get bothered about it every time I run update.

Comment: You may have GPG error. Look at this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/20725/gpg-error-the-following-signatures-couldnt-be-verified-because-the-public-key.

Comment: It seems that fixed it! Could you explain what exactly that does? Is the key still there? I'm also not sure how to mark your response as the solution since it is a comment.

Comment: Not really a solution because the problem was partially created by you due to lack of understanding of how software repositories work: Removing software does NOT remove the repository. The drivers you installed apparently added a repository with a signature issue that later may have been solved  by the link above. By now, it should be clear that you would have avoided all this by simple removing the repo after uninstalling the software said repo was required for.

Comment: @MichaelBay That's still enough to be a good answer for future visitors.