# How to handle phalconphp GPG issue

Tags: apt, gnupg

I'm trying to update my nodejs installation, and phalconphp is getting in the way. When I run `apt-get update`, I get this complaint

```
Err:13 https://packagecloud.io/phalcon/stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                        
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4166E80CDCF8B31B
```

Following the advice of several threads (such as [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20725/gpg-error-the-following-signatures-couldnt-be-verified-because-the-public-key)), I've tried to fetch the GPG key:

```
sudo gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 4166E80CDCF8B31B
```

Results in

```
gpg: requesting key DCF8B31B from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpgkeys: key 4166E80CDCF8B31B not found on keyserver
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
gpg: keyserver communications error: key not found
gpg: keyserver communications error: bad public key
gpg: keyserver receive failed: bad public key
```

So how do I figure out which server should have the GPG key?

Comment: @karel I added and accepted an answer below back in Jan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it by re-running the [phalcon install script](https://phalconphp.com/en/download/linux)

```
curl -s "https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/phalcon/stable/script.deb.sh" | sudo bash
```

This script has the URL to the correct key server and runs `apt-get add` on it (relevant portions here, feel free to read through the entire script though)

```
gpg_key_url="https://packagecloud.io/phalcon/stable/gpgkey"
# ...
curl -L "${gpg_key_url}" 2> /dev/null | apt-key add - &>/dev/null
```

Comment: How did that solve the missing key problem? I'm guessing it installed a newer key itself? You didn't need to run `apt-key`, or maybe the script did?

Comment: @Xen2050, the script has the correct URL for the key server and runs `apt-key add`. I've updated the answer with some details.